# ConversionPattern for arranging log messages in numerical order

Tags: java, log4j

I am implementing Log4j in my application , if i want the log messages to be numbered sequentially like 1,2,3 so what i need to append to this string

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = ? | %-7p | %-30F | %-5L | %-90m | %d %n
```

string at the place of "?" what can i write so my messages will be with sequence numbers.

Regards
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- `%r` is the number of milliseconds since log4j was started
- You can create a sortable date using `%d{ISO8601}` or your own custom format.

**[EDIT]** To number the log messages in sequence, you need to write your own `PatternLayout`. Override the method `createPatternParser()` to be able to use a custom pattern, say `%S`.

In `PatternParser`, override `finalizeConverter()` to add your own `PatternConverter` when `c == 'S'`:

```
protected
void finalizeConverter(char c) {
     if( 'S' == c ) return SequentialConverter.INSTANCE;
     else return super.finalizeConverter(c);
}
```

`SequentialConverter` needs to have a static counter. You can then override `format()` to add the counter to the log message:

```
public
void format(StringBuffer sbuf, LoggingEvent e) {
    sbuf.append( counter );
}
```

Comment: It works for me. If you would give me more information, I might be able tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: i want like this                                                                1) ..........log message.....
2)...........log message....
3)............log message....

Comment: Ah. There is no standard support for this. See my answer how to add it.